# Close dev tools cmd after chromedriver-selenium script job but keep chrome open

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Can't figure it out how to close the cmd (devtools) window once the chrome driver does it's job. I've a script that opens a webpage, logs in and does several tasks. Then I want the chrome.exe to stay open and the devtools window to close.

I ran the `.py` with a shortcut that points to a bat:

`"C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe"`
`"C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\Scripts2\\script_here.py" %*`

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.